# Custom bootloader does not access correct data during boot

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader

Just to note, I'm a noob with bootloaders and assembly, so I've been following a few (possibly not the best) examples.
I'm writing a bootloader in NASM for a project. It simply prints a string on the screen and waits for an Enter key. After the enter it loads another sector and prints a second string. Testing within VBox is great: the string is printed and everything works fine.

After testing it on a real computer, instead of the first string I get garbage. The second program works fine.
I'm using a custom script to write to floppy. All done under Linux Mint.
Sorry for any mistakes.

```
org 7c00h

start: 
    jmp short begin ; jump over the DOS boot record data
    ;----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ; data portion of the "DOS BOOT RECORD"
    ; ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;DOS data goes here
    ;------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mesaj db "Some string here" ,10
    len equ $-mesaj

begin:

    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 03h
    int 10h

    mov ah, 13h
    mov al, 0    
    mov cx, len
    mov bh, 0h
    mov bl, 02h      
    mov bp, mesaj
    mov dl, 20
    mov dh, 12
    int 10h ;printing the string

read:
    xor ah, ah
    int 16h ; read a key from keyboard
    cmp al, 0 
    jz read ; if special key, continue reading


    mov ah, 0Ah
    mov cx, 100
    mov bh, 0
    int 10h ; write keyboard character to screen
    cmp al, 0dh ; if character is Enter, load second program
    jne read

    ; loading the second sector
    mov ax, 0x500 
    mov es, ax    
    mov al, 1
    mov ch, 0
    mov cl, 2
    mov dh, 0
    mov dl, 0
    xor bx, bx

    mov ah, 2    
    int 0x13

    jmp 0x500:0
```

Comment: The 'print string' service requires the string pointer to be in `es:bp`. I see where you set `bp`. Where did you set `es`?

Comment: I didn't set it. As stated, I'm pretty new to assembly. Since everything worked fine in VirtualBox and none if the examples I read had es set before printing, I figured I don't need to set it...

Comment: The documentation for the call says `es:bp`. It's possible that in VirtualBox that `es` just happened to be set to what you needed (e.g., maybe set equal to `ds`). You can't assume that, though. It's always best to comply with the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make it work, thanks to mbratch's comment. Because `es` is not set, `es:bp` do not point to my string, but to some random place in memory.

The answer was to set `es` to 0, since I am working with absolute addresses (i.e. 7c00h). This works only if there is the `org 7c00h` at the start. If you don't want/can't use `org` set `es` to `7c0h`.

So, either:

```
org 7c00h
mov ax, 0
mov es, ax
```

or:

```
mov ax, 7c0h
mov es, ax
```

I got the info from http://wiki.osdev.org/Babystep2 and the idea from mbratch.